# What's a better way to define individual link colours for a url in a macro?

Tags: macros, hyperref, color, urls, links

I've got a document where I'd like two colours of links - cyan for links in headers that since it's brighter, and navy blue for links in the main body which is more subtle/less distracting. I already tried using the `xcolor` package and changing the text colour with `textcolor`, like `\textcolor{cyan}{\href{url.com}{link name}}`, but it doesn't override whatever link or url colour I have defined in `hypersetup`.

So this is what I've done:

I've defined the colour `navy`:

```
\definecolor{navy}{HTML}{2F729C}
```

And also imported the `hyperref` package and defined commands to set the global link/url colours to cyan / navy.

```
\usepackage{hyperref}                        
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=navy,urlcolor=navy}                       
\newcommand{\navylinks}{\hypersetup{linkcolor=navy,urlcolor=navy}}              
\newcommand{\bluelinks}{\hypersetup{linkcolor=cyan,urlcolor=cyan}}
```

Then I've defined another command specifically for the header links, where I turn on cyan links globally, include the header text and link, and then turn on navy links again:

```
\newcommand{\headerlink}[1]{\bluelinks\href{#2}{#1}\navylinks}
```

My issue with this is that I feel like there could be a better way to do it than to set the global link colour every time I use a link macro; is there a way to define the link colour just for *one* link, like one would do with `\textcolor{...}`, that would be able to override `hypersetup`?

Comment: Related: [How to use different colors for different \href commands?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61015/13304)

Answer (score 3):

**Preliminary remarks:**

- I would not change the link color inside headers. I think, it is more confusing than improving the readability.
- URLs inside chapter/section/... titles are a little debatable.
- My interpretation of "headers" are section titles inside the text, where the title is printed in larger font size and bold. But links in head lines or the table of contents  use the normal text link color.

Instead of different commands, I would change the behavior at such places, where the links should display differently. In case of `\section` (and `\subsection`, ...) titles, a good place is `\@sect`, where the eighth argument contains the section title. The seventh argument is used for the table of contents and the head lines.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{navy}{HTML}{2F729C}
\colorlet{linkcolor}{navy}
\colorlet{headerlinkcolor}{cyan}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}[2011/02/05]% option allcolors

\hypersetup{allcolors=linkcolor}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\org@sect}{}
\let\org@sect\@sect
\def\@sect#1#2#3#4#5#6[#7]#8{%
  \org@sect{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}[{#7}]{%
    \hypersetup{allcolors=headerlinkcolor}%
    #8%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{document}
% Test document that tries to put all cases in one page
\section{First chapter with URL
  \href{http://tex.stackexchange.com/}{TeX.SE}}
Link inside text: \href{http://tex.stackexchange.com/}{TeX.SE}.
\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Remarks:**

- There is a new option `allcolors` (and `allbordercolors`), that can
  be used as shortcut to set all color types (link, url, file, …) to the specified color (since `hyperref` 2011/02/05 v6.82a).

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you using the `xcolor` package. Then define a color you want the `hyperref` setup to refer to. Then in the headers simply redefine this color using, say, `\colorlet{mylinkcolor}{myheaderlinkcolor}`.

Here is an example

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{xcolor,hyperref,url}
\colorlet{links}{blue}
\hypersetup{
colorlinks=true,
urlcolor=links
}
\begin{document}

\url{hhh}

\colorlet{links}{red}

\url{hhh}

\end{document}
```

(Had a look at one of my own constructions, turnes out, I did the same as you, reissued `\hyperretup`, but the example above show that the color is just a reference.

Answer (score 2):

I would just use the `\color` macro *inside* the `\href` instead of outside, i.e. `\href{url.com}{\color{cyan}{link name}}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue}

\begin{document}

\color{red}{This is red text, \href{http://example.com}{but the links are still blue}.}

\href{http://example.com}{\color{red}{This is a red link.}}

\end{document}
```