# Change hyperref "linkcolor" for a single instance only?

Tags: hyperref

Using the following bit of code in an otherwise black text:

```
\color[HTML]{636060}27.~Mai/1.~Juni: Gegenregierung in Kanton unter Sun Ke (☞~S.~\pageref{bio:SunKe}). Diese wird im Dez. von Nanking kooptiert.
```

produces the required grey paragraph, except that the referenced page number is still displayed in black.

The relevant line in the preamble is:

```
\usepackage[colorlinks,filecolor=black,linkcolor=black,citecolor=black,urlcolor=black,breaklinks,pdfa]{hyperref}
```

changing that to e.g.: `\usepackage[colorlinks,filecolor=black,
%linkcolor=black,
citecolor=black,urlcolor=black,breaklinks,pdfa]{hyperref}`

of course defaults ALL references to red. As far as the hyperref documentation is concerned “23  Localized nullifying of package” appears to be relevant. I can't make sense of that code.

Summing up the question: Is there a (simple) way of definig linkcolor (here [HTML]{636060}) for a single/few instances only?

Comment: this answer seems like exactly what you need https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/120844/90297

Answer (score 5):

You could change the link color locally to another color:

```
{\hypersetup{linkcolor=red}\pageref{...}}
```

With the special color `.` the current text color is used:

```
{\color{red} Text \hypersetup{linkcolor=.}\pageref{...}}
```

Maybe you can use `linkcolor=.` for the document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks,breaklinks,pdfa,
  linkcolor=.
]{hyperref}

\definecolor{specialtext}{HTML}{636060}

\begin{document}
\section{Color test}
\label{sec:test}

Text

Black link: \pageref{sec:test}

\textcolor{red}{Red text with red link: \pageref{sec:test}}

{\color{specialtext}Gray text with gray link: \pageref{sec:test}}

Black link again: \pageref{sec:test}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Works fine as suggested.

Comment: I think in your second example, where you use the dot operator you also have to use `linkcolor` instead of the present `color`. at least it didn't work for me with just `color`.

Comment: @NathanaelSkrepek Thanks for the hint. I have changed it.