# Two \cite commands with different colored links?

Tags: hyperref, cite-package

I'm writing a grant proposal (whee) and I was given a suggestion to make two different citations with two different colors.  So it would be something like:

```
In the PI's prior work~\citeme{mycoolpaper} he proved a cool theorem; 
subsequent follow-up work by others~\cite{otherpaper} provided empirical 
validation on several benchmark data sets.
```

In the formatting `\citeme{}` would be colored red, and `\cite{}` blue, using `\hypersetup{}` or something like that.

I know that one can do this with [\href](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61015/how-to-use-different-colors-for-different-href-commands), but I wasn't sure if you could specify a custom `\cite` command.

I feel like some combination of the `cite` and `hyperref` and maybe `biblatex` would do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following example defines `\citeme` and changes the `citecolor` inside a group. Care is taken to support the optional argument of `\cite`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\citeme}{%
  \begingroup
  \hypersetup{citecolor=red}%
  \@ifnextchar[\citeme@opt\citeme@
}
\def\citeme@opt[#1]#2{%
  \cite[{#1}]{#2}%
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand*{\citeme@}[1]{%
  \cite{#1}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

In the PI's prior work~\citeme{mycoolpaper} he proved a cool theorem;
subsequent follow-up work by others~\cite{otherpaper} provided empirical
validation on several benchmark data sets.

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{mycoolpaper}
  Me: Cool Title.

\bibitem{otherpaper}
  Someone else: Hot Title.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]