# Making URLs non-clickable with hyperref

Tags: hyperref

I've been told that I have to make all URLs in the bibliography for this document non-clickable. However, I am using `hyperref` to do internal linking within the document (c.f. [citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/188275/two-cite-commands-with-different-colored-links)).

I looked at the package options for `hyperref` but couldn't find an option to make URLs non-clickable.  Is there a secret hack?

**Update 1:**  Here's an MWE that shows that modifying `href` seemed not to work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand\href[3][\relax]{#3}

Here's a cite:~\cite{ChaudhuriMS:11pperm}.


\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{example}
\end{document}
```

example.bib:

```
@article{ChaudhuriMS:11pperm,
    Author = {Kamalika Chaudhuri and Claire Monteleoni and Anand Dilip Sarwate},
    Date-Added = {2014-07-15 22:54:03 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-07-15 22:54:03 +0000},
    Journal = {Journal of Machine Learning Research},
    Local-Url = {pdfs/ChaudhuriMS11erm.pdf},
    Month = {March},
    Pages = {1069--1109},
    Title = {Differentially private empirical risk minimization},
    Url = {http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/v12/chaudhuri11a.html},
    Volume = {12},
    Year = {2011},
    Bdsk-Url-1 = {http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/v12/chaudhuri11a.html}}
```

I am getting an warning:  `Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.` Is that undoing the href redefinition?  Note I'm using pdflatex on MacOS.

**Update 2:**  Here's a new MWE -- it seems that if I put a `\newpage` before the references, it makes all URLs clickable, and if not, then the fix works... I can hack this in my document but I find this behavior a bit... unexpected?  Does `\newpage` clear some settings?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{ChaudhuriMS:11pperm,
    Author = {Kamalika Chaudhuri and Claire Monteleoni and Anand Dilip Sarwate},
    Journal = {Journal of Machine Learning Research},
    Month = {March},
    Pages = {1069--1109},
    Title = {Differentially private empirical risk minimization},
    Url = {http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/v12/chaudhuri11a.html},
    Volume = {12},
    Year = {2011}}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

Here is a cite: \cite{ChaudhuriMS:11pperm}.

\newpage % comment to make URL not clickable

\let\url\nolinkurl% Make \url be equivalent to \nolinkurl
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

**Update 3:**  Here's the .bbl file that is produced by TeXShop (perhaps I should return to the command line?).  I still get that the link is non-clickable if and only if the `\newpage` is commented out.  The .bbl file is *identical* whether I comment or don't comment the `\newpage` command.

```
% Generated by IEEEtran.bst, version: 1.13 (2008/09/30)
\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\providecommand{\url}[1]{#1}
\csname url@samestyle\endcsname
\providecommand{\newblock}{\relax}
\providecommand{\bibinfo}[2]{#2}
\providecommand{\BIBentrySTDinterwordspacing}{\spaceskip=0pt\relax}
\providecommand{\BIBentryALTinterwordstretchfactor}{4}
\providecommand{\BIBentryALTinterwordspacing}{\spaceskip=\fontdimen2\font plus
\BIBentryALTinterwordstretchfactor\fontdimen3\font minus
  \fontdimen4\font\relax}
\providecommand{\BIBforeignlanguage}[2]{{%
\expandafter\ifx\csname l@#1\endcsname\relax
\typeout{** WARNING: IEEEtran.bst: No hyphenation pattern has been}%
\typeout{** loaded for the language `#1'. Using the pattern for}%
\typeout{** the default language instead.}%
\else
\language=\csname l@#1\endcsname
\fi
#2}}
\providecommand{\BIBdecl}{\relax}
\BIBdecl

\bibitem{ChaudhuriMS:11pperm}
\BIBentryALTinterwordspacing
K.~Chaudhuri, C.~Monteleoni, and A.~D. Sarwate, ``Differentially private
  empirical risk minimization,'' \emph{Journal of Machine Learning Research},
  vol.~12, pp. 1069--1109, March 2011. [Online]. Available:
  \url{http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/v12/chaudhuri11a.html}
\BIBentrySTDinterwordspacing

\end{the bibliography}
```

**Update 4:**  This phenomenon seems particular to Apple's Preview PDF reader (the solution given by [Werner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5764/werner) works great if you view the PDF in Adobe.  I still have no idea why `\newpage` causes this difference, but at least I now have plausible deniability about the URLs.  Thanks!

Comment: How are the URLs entered into the bibliography?  A [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) would help users diagnose the issue.

Comment: Added an example above, sorry for not getting that earlier.

Comment: Did you tried to clear your `aux` file? Note that in @AnandSarwate 's answer, `\renewcommand\href[3][\relax]{#3}` was intended to be place **just before** `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To de-activate the URL capability in the bibliography, set `\url` to be equivalent to `\nolinkurl` (also provided by [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref); see section **4 Additional user macros** of the [`hyperref` HTML documentation](http://ctan.cms.math.ca/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.html#x1-140004)):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{ChaudhuriMS:11pperm,
    Author = {Kamalika Chaudhuri and Claire Monteleoni and Anand Dilip Sarwate},
    Date-Added = {2014-07-15 22:54:03 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-07-15 22:54:03 +0000},
    Journal = {Journal of Machine Learning Research},
    Local-Url = {pdfs/ChaudhuriMS11erm.pdf},
    Month = {March},
    Pages = {1069--1109},
    Title = {Differentially private empirical risk minimization},
    Url = {http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/v12/chaudhuri11a.html},
    Volume = {12},
    Year = {2011},
    Bdsk-Url-1 = {http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/v12/chaudhuri11a.html}}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

Here's a cite:~\cite{ChaudhuriMS:11pperm}.

\let\url\nolinkurl% Make \url be equivalent to \nolinkurl
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That is a nice answer,but I think that for the sake of generality you should preserve then restore the original `\url` command, as Andrew did in his answer.

Comment: Weirdly, this work on the MEW, but not in the full text of my document.  The links are not blue anymore, but they are still clickable...

Comment: @AnandSarwate: Then we need more information...

Comment: Added a new MWE... it seems `\newpage` is the culprit?

Comment: @AnandSarwate: No problem here - the URL is still *not* clickable. Are you rerunning BibTeX with the change in setup? You'll see that if you open up the `.bbl` file, it prints the URL using `\url{...}`. So, resetting `\url` to be the same as `\nolinkurl`, I don't see how it could now work (regardless of a `\newpage` or not).

Comment: Maybe it's my BibTeX installation... attaching the .bbl that's produced above.

Comment: @AnandSarwate: Have you tried viewing it in a different browser? I've tried compiling with all possible compilers (LaTeX > dvips > ps2pdf, pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, LauLaTeX) and nothing seems to produce the URL hyperlinked, when viewed in Adobe.

Comment: Ah it must be the PDF reader! In Preview on MacOS I get the phenomenon (newpage --> clickable) but in Adobe it's not clickable. So confusing!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are using `hyperref` in the standard way then the links in the bibliography are being created using `\href`. You can disable these links by redefining the `\href` command just before your bibliography starts. As the syntax for `\href` is

```
\href[optional arguments]{url}{text}
```

you want to pick up the third argument to `\href` and discard the rest (`#1` is the optional argument). Therefore, you need something like the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\cite{one_paper}
\cite{another_paper}
\begin{document}

\renewcommand\href[3][\relax]{#3}     % this is the crucial line

\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{mypapers}
\end{\document}
```

If you have links made with hyperref that appear after your bibliography then you should "save" the original `\href` command and then restore it afterwards:

```
\let\orighref=\href
\renewcommand\href[3][\relax]{#3}  
\bibliography{mypapers}
\let\href=\orighref
```

Comment: It doesn't quite seem to work for me (see edited example above) -- but maybe it's my rendering pipeline?

Comment: This solution also doesn't work in the new MWE above -- the link is still colored and clickable.

Comment: @AnandSarwate The reason that my solution doesn't work with your MWE is that your "Update 3" shows that the links in your bibliography are created using `\url` rather than with `\href`. In any case, the solution provided by @werner is better, not only because it works for you but because it directly addresses the problem with `\url`.