# Customize colours with \ref

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

I want to create a command alternative to `\ref` to distinguish links between 2 different colours (say, black and red).

In my code below I have simply use the answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61015/how-to-use-different-colors-for-different-href-commands) and replaced `\href` with `\ref`. It does not work but I don't know how to fix it.

```
\documentclass[10 pt,a4paper,oneside,openany, notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, graphics}

\usepackage[colorlinks = true,
            linkcolor = black,
            urlcolor  = black,
            citecolor = black,
            anchorcolor = black]{hyperref}

\newcommand\MYref[3][red]{\ref{#2}{\color{#1}{#3}}}% %NEW COMMAND ALTERNATIVE TO REF


\begin{document}

\section{Title}
\label{blah}
\begin{equation}
\label{eq1}
A=B
\end{equation}

See Section \MYref{blah2}

See Equation \ref{eq1} or \MYref{eq1}

\newpage
\section{Title2}
\label{blah2}

\end{document}
```

What I want is the link (to an equation, section, subsection, figure, etc) displaying in red when I use `\Myref` and displaying in black when I use `\ref`.

Comment: Your setup is confusing: You define `\MYref` as taking 3 arguments (one being optional) in the preamble, yet to invoke the macro with just 1 argument in the body of the document. Please clarify what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: As Mico says, what are you trying to do and why have you removed the color of the hyperlink? If you just want certain hyplerlinked references to be colored, then that can easily be done via local color redefinitions. But please explainwhat exactly you are trying to do

Comment: Your not using the 3rd argument actually and `article` does not know the `openany` option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `\hypersetup{linkcolor=red}` command in a `\begingroup...\endgroup` pair within your `\MYref` pair.

I've used `xparse` to provide the 3rd. optional argument which is not given here at all in the examples.

```
\documentclass[10 pt,a4paper,oneside, notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, graphics}

\usepackage[colorlinks = true,
            linkcolor = black,
            urlcolor  = black,
            citecolor = black,
            anchorcolor = black]{hyperref}

\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\MYref}{O{red}mo}{%
  \begingroup
  \hypersetup{linkcolor=#1}%
  \ref{#2}%
  \IfValueT{#3}{%
    \color{#1}{#3}%
  }%
  \endgroup
}% %NEW COMMAND ALTERNATIVE TO REF

\newcommand\MYreforig[3][red]{\begingroup\hypersetup{linkcolor=#1}\ref{#2}{\color{#1}{#3}}\endgroup}% %NEW COMMAND ALTERNATIVE TO REF


\begin{document}

\section{Title}
\label{blah}
\begin{equation}
\label{eq1}
A=B
\end{equation}

See Section \MYref{blah2}

See Equation \ref{eq1} or \MYref{eq1}

\newpage
\section{Title2}
\label{blah2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: perhaps easier to just change the color, `\colorlet{linkColor}{black}` and set `linkcolor = linkColor` in the preamble. Then `\colorlet{linkColor}{#1}` in the macro instead of the `\hypersetup` (BTW shouldn't `linkcolor=red` be `linkcolor=#1` in your code?)

Comment: @daleif: Yes, it should be `#1` instead of `red`, that was too fast by me. The idea with `\colorlet` is very nice, in fact.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer the code above creates problem when used in footnotes and when used with figures

Comment: @user3285148: Which problems? There are no footnotes or figures in your example file

Comment: Apologies, I have just seen the new \MYref which works perfectly also with footnotes and  figures. \MYreforig when used inside a footnote does not put a space after the link (the same with figures). Thank you

Comment: @user3285148: Because your old `\MYref` definition used 3 arguments, i.e \MYreforig looks for a 3rd argument and gobbles the space