# How to give \href's different options without macros or global defaults?

Tags: hyperref, href

I am trying to have the two `\href` in the code below behave with different options **without having to invoke macros or global defaults**.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\href{www.overleaf.com}{link1}
\href{www.overleaf.com}{link2}

\end{document}
```

The idea is that one of them will continue with default and to pass the second one, I believe, the `hidelinks = true` option: **keep clickable property but remove default blue box**.  I've seen many examples showing how to do this with macros but since I only want to have the non-default behavior very few times, I prefer to have the **option scoped to the `\href` directly**.

This is very similar in spirit to the answer given by @CephBirk in [How to use different colors for different \href commands?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61015/how-to-use-different-colors-for-different-href-commands) but I can't figure out how to make it work to remove the box instead of changing the color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options you pass to `\href` are passed to a `href` option group, but the options that handle the link appearance belong to the `Hyp` option group. If you don't want to keep the interface to the `href` option group then this is enough:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\Myhref}[1][]{% definition copied form hyperref.sty
  \begingroup
  \setkeys{Hyp}{#1}% Changed href to Hyp
  \@ifnextchar\bgroup\Hy@href{\hyper@normalise\href@}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\Myhref{www.overleaf.com}{link1}

\Myhref[hidelinks]{www.overleaf.com}{link2}

\Myhref{www.overleaf.com}{link3}

\end{document}
```

which prints:

[image]

If you are still going to use the standard options to `\href` then you have to do a little more:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\Myhref}[1][]{%
  \begingroup
  \hypersetup{#1}%
  \inner@href % Call an "inner href"
}
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\inner@href}[1][]{%
  \setkeys{href}{#1}%
  \@ifnextchar\bgroup\Hy@href{\hyper@normalise\href@}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\Myhref{www.overleaf.com}{link1}

\Myhref[hidelinks]{www.overleaf.com}{link2}

\Myhref{www.overleaf.com}{link3}

\end{document}
```

Then the `\Myhref` command has *two* optional arguments:

```
\Myhref[<Hyp-options>][<href-options>]{<link>}{<text>}
```

Comment: What is the difference between the 2 options?

Comment: Would a mix of \Myhref and \href work or should I replace all the \href's?

Comment: Sorry, final question... Is there an option that hover would reveal the text in the Myhref in addition to hidelinks?

Comment: @ranlot Sorry, I had to leave for a while. 1) If you used the `\href` command with options (`\href[<something>]{}{}`), then you need the second approach, otherwise the first will do. 2) You can still use `\href` normally. The `\Myhref` just creates a wrapper to change options. 3) That is a completely different question (that I really have no idea about the answer, sorry), so I suggest you ask a new question. Hope this helps :)