# Use customized color in \href

Tags: hyperref, color, resume, cv

### Problem

I am now updating my CV and I want to replace the ugly block outside the hyperlink with the customized color. I read and tried the solution provided in these answers and websites ([anwser1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61015/how-to-use-different-colors-for-different-href-commands), [answer2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/823/remove-ugly-borders-around-clickable-cross-references-and-hyperlinks) help specify appearance of `\href` and [website](http://latexcolor.com/) provide a long list of colors I could use) but I am facing three issues

- After defining color as per the website, I use the customized color in `\MYhref`, but the output seems to be pale all the time.
- In the two solutions, `\href` is configured with `urlcolor`, `citecolor`, etc. However, I do not understand how the system knows the input format and determine the corresponding color (maybe regular expressions?). At the same time, I could not use the customized color here. It turns out to be pale all the time no matter what color I use.
- I really like the color shown in this CV snapshot, but how do I know the parameters (RGB values) and use it in my CV?

[image]

EDIT:
Here is an MWE and resulting output. Note this example requires `res.cls`, which could be downloaded [here](https://www.math.nyu.edu/student_resources/res.cls).
[image]

```
\documentclass[margin,line,pifont,palatino,courier]{res}

\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage[latin1] {inputenc}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{}
% definition of color and href
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{0.33, 0.41, 0.58}
\newcommand{\myhref}[3][blue]{\href{#2}{\color{#1}{#3}}}

\newenvironment{list1}{
  \begin{list}{\ding{113}}{%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{0in}
      \setlength{\parsep}{0in} \setlength{\parskip}{0in}
      \setlength{\topsep}{0in} \setlength{\partopsep}{0in}
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{0.17in}}}{\end{list}}
\newenvironment{list2}{
  \begin{list}{$\bullet$}{%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{0in}
      \setlength{\parsep}{0in} \setlength{\parskip}{0in}
      \setlength{\topsep}{0in} \setlength{\partopsep}{0in}
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{0.2in}}}{\end{list}}

\begin{document}

\name{David Smith \vspace*{.1in}}
%\title{firstlast_cv}
\begin{resume}

\section{\sc Contact Information}

\vspace{.05in}
% use the number to adjust the column width
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{2in}p{3in}}
2500 Wonder Land
&Phone: (123) 456-7890 \\
Ogeid Nas, CA 12345                    
&Email: \myhref[myblue]{abc@xyz.org}{abc@xyz.org}\\
&Website: 
\myhref[myblue]{abc.xyz.org}{abc.xyz.org}
\\
\end{tabular}

\end{resume}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The blue can be implemented via `\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{33,22,92}`, I think. There exist applications called `color picker` and so on which allow you to pick a color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, that the url seems to be pale comes from the white background and the small font. The defined blue color has not such an contrast the black font has.

You can try to make the url bold like

```
\newcommand{\myhref}[3][blue]{\href{#2}{\color{#1}\textbf{{#3}}}}
%                                                 ^^^^^^^^    ^
```

Then the used font is thicker and is seen better.

The following code

```
\documentclass[margin,line,pifont,palatino,courier]{res}

\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage[latin1] {inputenc}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{}
% definition of color and href
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{0.33, 0.41, 0.58}
\newcommand{\myhref}[3][blue]{\href{#2}{\color{#1}\textbf{{#3}}}}% <=============

\newenvironment{list1}{
  \begin{list}{\ding{113}}{%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{0in}
      \setlength{\parsep}{0in} \setlength{\parskip}{0in}
      \setlength{\topsep}{0in} \setlength{\partopsep}{0in}
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{0.17in}}}{\end{list}}
\newenvironment{list2}{
  \begin{list}{$\bullet$}{%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{0in}
      \setlength{\parsep}{0in} \setlength{\parskip}{0in}
      \setlength{\topsep}{0in} \setlength{\partopsep}{0in}
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{0.2in}}}{\end{list}}

\begin{document}

\name{David Smith \vspace*{.1in}}
%\title{firstlast_cv}
\begin{resume}

\section{\sc Contact Information}

\vspace{.05in}
% use the number to adjust the column width
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{2in}p{3in}}
2500 Wonder Land
&Phone: (123) 456-7890 \\
Ogeid Nas, CA 12345                    
&Email: \myhref[myblue]{abc@xyz.org}{abc@xyz.org}\\
&Website: 
\myhref[myblue]{abc.xyz.org}{abc.xyz.org}
\\
\end{tabular}

\end{resume}
\end{document}
```

results in:

[image: resulting pdf]

You did not say if you mean the printed version to be pale or the version on the screen, but the problem always is that a printed color is not the same color you see on your screen (or you have a calibrated (expensiv) system, showing the same color on screen and paper of special printer). If you print the paper on two different printers you will not get the same color on both ...

Depending on your used software there are tools, for example the color picker @marmot mentioned in his comment, or others. But that tools picks only the color on the screen and that color may not be the printed.

Just play with the color until you are satisfied with the screen version **or** the printed version.