# anchorcolor in hyperref not working?

Tags: hyperref, color, hyperlink, hypertarget

I am trying to use the `hyperref` package to color internal links coming from `\label` as green, while those coming from anchored text via `\hypertarget` as red. However, in both cases, the relevant text appears green?
I am using `revtex4-1`, but I don't think that this is the problem ...

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage[pdftex]{xcolor}
\usepackage[pdftex,breaklinks,colorlinks,
linkcolor=green,
anchorcolor=red]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
   \text{this is an equation} \label{theeq}
\end{equation}

This is the equation \ref{theeq} and it is green as expected.\\
\hypertarget{thelink}{This should be anchored}
\hyperlink{thelink}{ But its color is not red?}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe help this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/61016/31034

Comment: It doesn't look as if the anchor color is used for pdflatex/luatex. I found it only in some of the more exotic drivers like textures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I suppose you report this bug to the maintainer of `hyperref`.

Until it is corrected you can use the following workaround:

```
\newcommand{\myhypertarget}[3][red]{\hypertarget{#2}{\textcolor{#1}{#3}}}%
```

Command `\myhypertarget` sets the colour `red` manually to the target text.

With the following MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[%
  breaklinks,
  colorlinks,
  linkcolor=green,
  anchorcolor=red
]{hyperref}

\newcommand{\myhypertarget}[3][red]{\hypertarget{#2}{\textcolor{#1}{#3}}}%


\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
   \text{this is an equation} \label{theeq}
\end{equation}

This is the equation \ref{theeq} and it is green as expected.\\
\hypertarget{thelink}{This should be anchored}

And this is with \texttt{\\myhypertarget}: 
\myhypertarget{thelink1}{This should be anchored}
Text between target and link. Text between target and link. 
Text between target and link. Text between target and link. 
\hyperlink{thelink}{ But its color is not red?}

\hyperlink{thelink1}{ But its color is not red?}

\end{document}
```

you get the result:

[image: resulting pdf]

Please see that I deleted the driver `pdftex` for `xcolor` and `hyperref`. Also I used class `revtex4-2`, the current version of revtex.